# How to get class from html in python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

hey so im trying to make a btc price checker in python I've already wrote most of it but on the site there is a html to an image that is an up arrow or a down arrow this is the html code

```
<span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>
```

so in my code I would do

```
if class == str("icon-Caret-down"):
    print("Negative Percentage: -" + percentage")
else:
   print("Positive Percentage: " + percentage")
```

"percentage" is already defined in my code

Comment: What library are you currently using? (also there's an unescaped quotation in your code snippet, might wanna fix that)

Comment: im using lxml e

Comment: What issues are you facing? Can you post a full code? Also, in lines 2 and 4 there are extra `"`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `bs4` module:

```
import bs4

if __name__ == "__main__":
    html = """<span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>"""

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    for span in soup.find_all("span"):
        if span["class"][0] == "icon-Caret-down":
            # do stuff
```

Documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/